# Stop watch in android withtimer starting from the top

Tags: android

I want a stop watch for an android quiz application but it should run from the top.I mean it should set the time for example 2 hrs for the application and then should come down from 2 hrs to 0 as the quiz moves on..How can we implement this in android????

Comment: I think you can use chronometer for this. check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use countdown timer.

Refer the link.

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html
```

Hope following code helps you out :)

```
final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long

                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                         textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                      //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                     }

                     public void onFinish() {
                         textView.setText("done!");
                     }
                    }
                    .start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can we use it for hours and minutes to decrement also?

Comment: I want hours and minutes to increment also

Comment: ya just put that much seconds.e.g.: here i have 30 sec timer,so i have 30000.You can add appropriate value for 2 hrs as per your requirement.